# Subdomain Redirect - passing username/password

Tags: redirect, ftp, subdomain

I have created a subdomain for our website - ftp.orban.com - and have it redirecting to another ftp that I created that passes a username and password through the URL so that the user isn't prompted for one.

My Subdomain is:ftp.orban.com
My Document root is:/public_html/ftpdownloads
And my Redirection is: ftp://ftpdownloads@orban.com:12345@107.180.55.1/

I can get my ftp.orban.com domain to point to this new directory but I'm still being promoted for a username and password.  Do you know why the username and password is not working and how I can get this to work so that the directory is open to the public?

Thanks for your help.
Claudia